# Caliburn.Micro view switching

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In a CM WPF application I have following items:

```
<Window> <!-- Shell Window -->
 <ContentControl x:Name="MainRegion">
 <ContentControl x:Name="SearchRegion">
<Window>
```

Views:

```
MainRegionView
SearchRegionView
```

View Models:

```
MainRegionViewModel //implements Conductor<Screen>
SearchRegionViewModel //implements Conductor<Screen>
```

I neet to switch the view of SearchRegionViewModel from MainRegionViewModel.
Following code is executed **inside MainRegionViewModel**.

```
ViewModelTest test = new ViewModelTest();
//Calling the method from object reference
searchRegionViewModel.ActivateItem(test);
```

**Problem:**
the view is not loaded in SearchRegionView.
How can i load the view to SearchRegion?

Comment: If i add the following  code `ViewModelTest test = new ViewModelTest();
this.ActivateItem(test);` inside SearchRegionViewModel's constructor then the view is loaded. I have no idea about why its not loading when calling  ActivateItem() from object reference.

Comment: Because what you actually have here is a "multiple" view with multiple viewmodel setup (a whole different idea).  What you could can do if you want view switching per se, is change up the layout to have 1 `<ContentControl x:Name=ActiveItem />` with said name.  Then when you call ActivateItem(test) then the view will actually switch out and the viewmodel will be associated it that ViewModel that was switched to.

Comment: Both views could be visible at runtime if you wanted, view switching wouldn't be necessary if you had properties named exactly as you named the contentcontrols with respect to their respective viewmodels, think of it as a composite view.  Of course if they overlap either other, then only one will be visible.

Comment: Yes, I'm having two separate regions to load views. Actually i'm trying to load the _SearchView_ in a separate region. I'm using MahApps Metro flyout for loading the _SearchView_. So the flyout is  showing up, but the view is not loaded on it. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, Create a property of type SearchRegionViewModel name it SearchRegion, instantiate it.  Once this is done it should be populated.  This all should be done in the Shell's ViewModel

Comment: I tried but i'ts not working :(. If I call method `ActivateItem()` inside SearchRegionViewModel's constructor, then it works. I don't know why.

Comment: Something I missing anyway you could post a sample project?

Comment: Oh yeah... your viewmodels for search and main should inherit Screen not `Conductor<Screen>` unless you have intent of the Main and the Search to host other "Screens".  The only one that "should' inherit `Conductor<Screen>` or some derivative of that is the ShellViewModel, which would then be used to Activate and Deactivate viewmodels that ActiveItem would hold.  In addition my previous example would work once they are "Screens" not Conductors.  Cedric is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainRegionViewModel` & `SearchRegionView` need to implement Screen and your `ShellViewModel` is the one that need to implement the Conductor. After that, you need to bind the ActiveItem in the XAML (ShellView.xaml).

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"></ContentControl>
```

Inside your ShellViewModel use `Activate(YourViewModel)`.

Here is an [Example](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/CaliburnMicroApp_Navigation.zip)

If you want to change the ActiveItem inside your MainRegionViewModel, You need to look at the [EventAggregator](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator) to publish a message to your ShellViewModel to `Activate` the desire ViewModel